# How to load iPhone Contacts very quickly in my ios App

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, abaddressbook, addressbookui

I have more than 20,000 contacts in my iPhone, i need to show all those contacts in the application very quickly, but i need to compare every iphone contact with my core data attribute named as "**phonenumber**" matched or not, For this im using "**NSPredicate**" for filtering quickly.

Here my quick doubt is, how can i get all contacts very quickly, when i update the contact or delete the contact from my iphone and update need update those contacts on my app simultaneously.

Comment: Probably some background synchronization will be good idea. The API works slow if you want to fetch all contacts.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski Thanks for quick reply, I tried background thread, but its something sticky, but when i try to update contact like delete or edit,  its need to update quickly on my app side 

    Is there any possibility to get 100 to 100 records like load more functionality.